# I keep on getting these errors. Yii and Pear

Tags: php, mysql, apache, yii, pear

Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\northwind/../../framework/yii.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\northwind\index.php on line 12

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\northwind/../../framework/yii.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\northwind\index.php on line 12

I keep on getting this error.

----THE CODE----

```
<?php

// change the following paths if necessary
$yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/../../framework/yii.php';
$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/main.php';

// remove the following lines when in production mode
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true);
// specify how many levels of call stack should be shown in each log message
defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL') or define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL',3);

require_once($yii);
Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();
```

---

My previous works won't work anymore. After I installed yii on xamp. or it has nothing to do with my yii? how about the pear? I kinda confuse.

sorry I'm a newbie.I badly need help.

SO I tried putting include_path=".;C:\xampp\php\PEAR" then the error now is
**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in C:\xampp\htdocs\northwind\index.php on line 13**

Comment: errors seem clear to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 1):

Framework path is incorrect, please check the path.
Do you have the framework? If you don't know, please download [Yii framework](http://www.yiiframework.com/download/)

Comment: downloaded the framework already. I think I got the path wrong. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Forward slashes ("/") in filenames will not work on Windows. Change them to back slashes ("\"), and verify that the `C:\xampp\framework\yii.php` file does, in fact, exist.